# Override 3ed party CSS conditionally

Tags: css, angular

In my component, I  would like to have the option to override a CSS class added by a third library component lib by condition.
so, if the user passing true while using the component, it will use my class implementation, otherwise, use the 3ed library class.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ng class on the element as follows:

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class': condition==true, '3d-party-class':condition==false}"
```

Comment: Not possible.
My class should override the 3ed party class - it means they have the exact same name. 
Also, its the 3ed party component so I can't add classes to it.